# Finding a basis for a set of $2\times2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Find a basis for $M_{2\times2}$ containing the matrices $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

I know that every $2\times2$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ can be written as:

$$a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  + c \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  + d \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

so those matrices are a basis for the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices, but how do I apply this to specific matrices? I know how to find a basis for a set of vectors, but matrices confuse me.

Comment: Could you find a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ containing $(1,1,2,3)$ and $(1,1,3,2)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Would I row reduce $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ to get $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ so that the basis is {(0,1,1,0), (-5,1,1,0)}?

Comment: that is not a basis of $\Bbb R^4$. That's one of the tricky parts here.

Comment: Oh I see that now... I'm still pretty confused on how to solve my problem then..

Comment: The other tricky part is seeing that my question is pretty much the same as the one you were given

Comment: @Omnomnomnom any suggestions on how to work through the tricky parts?

Comment: [These ones are very convenient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a systematic approach: to begin, find a basis for $\Bbb R^4$ containing the vectors $(1,1,2,3)$ and $(1,1,3,2)$.  Following the method [that I outline here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463292/find-a-basis-of-v-containing-v-and-w/463296#463296), we find that $\{(1,1,2,3),(1,1,3,2),(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^4$.  Correspondingly,
$$
\left\{\pmatrix{1&1\\2&3},
\pmatrix{1&1\\3&2},
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
\right\}
$$
is a basis for $M_{2 \times 2}$

Answer (score 2):

The two matrices are linearly independent, so they are a basis for the  two dimensional vector space spanned by them.

If you want a basis for $M_{2\times2}$ add two linearly independent matrices that are linearly independent from them. As an example you can chose:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: but the question asks that you extend this to a basis of $M_{2\times 2}$

Comment: @Emilio Novati What does this tell me about the basis of these matrices?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I see , and I add to my answer.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I don't think your suggestion works; the last matrix would be a linear combination of the other ones (in the given order: $M_4 = M_2-M_1+M_3)$

Comment: @StackTD: Right! I edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with more *trial & error*-like approaches, or go for a more systematic approach. If you can easily add two linearly independent matrices "*by inspection*", then you are done. This is doable in your case (see [Emilio Novati's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2184694/159845)) but can get hard(er) in a more general case.

---

Knowing the standard basis, you could look at:
$$\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}$$
Because the last 4 matrices form a basis for $M_{2 \times 2}$, this set clearly spans $M_{2 \times 2}$. But since $M_{2 \times 2}$ is 4-dimensional, this set cannot be linearly independent. Work from left to right and omit any matrix which can be written as a linear combination of the matrices before; i.e. deleting the linearly dependent matrices to end up with a basis for $M_{2 \times 2}$ containing the given two matrices.

This can be done in a more systematic way by entering the matrices in columns, identifying the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with the column vector $(a,b,c,d)^T$ and then row reducing this matrix; the linearly independent columns (and thus corresponding matrices) will be the pivot columns. This approach is explained in [Omnomnomnom's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2184726/159845) as well.

---

Alternatively, you can check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000385/finding-a-basis-need-help-finding-vectors-which-arent-linear-combinations-of/2000459#2000459) for another systematic approach. I'll leave out the details here, but identifying the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with the vector $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$, this comes down to finding a basis for the null space of the matrix ([WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=null+%7B%7B1,1,2,3%7D,%7B1,1,3,2%7D%7D)):
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
So a basis would also be:
$$\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} -5 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}$$

Comment: if I put the matrices into columns of a larger matrix, I get $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1&1&1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&1&0&0\\2&3&0&0&1&0\\3&2&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ which row reduces to $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1&1&1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&-2&0&1&0\\0&0&1&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&-5&1&1\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. From here, I am wondering where you got the last 2 vectors in your answer for the basis.

Comment: @AmaC that is the method I described before (see also Omnomnomnom's answer); note that you can further reduce to clearly identify the pivot colums. The two matrices in the last part of my answer are the result of a different method. I descibe it in more detail in another answer (see link).

Comment: And if you were wondering why they are / can be different; a basis is not unique so extending your two matrices to a complete basis can also be done in multiple ways (an _infinite_ number of ways, in fact).